# How to make a list view of places are in google maps?

Tags: android-studio

i am new in android developement . currently i am working on an app that shows the nearest pharmacies 
i succeded in showing them on the map but i want to make the activity half map and half listview which the list view should have the pharmacies ordered from the nearest one to the most far one

this is the xml of my MapActivity

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:clickable="true"

       />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

this is the list item



     <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
            android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
            tools:background="@android:color/white"
            />
```

i want to show the places i got from the map on the list and ordered but i dont know how

Answer (score 0):

There is a really helpful tutorial that I followed a while back, especially under the heading "**Showing Places in ListView**" that might be helpful for you. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/ Just taking a quick glance at your code, I think you are missing a `<ListView>` element in your MapActivity.xml and your List item needs a `Layout` element in order to know where to display the list. Take a look at the above referenced tutorial and it gives you some example code. Hope it helps!